# Can I build a Dockerfile without having it predefined as an actual file? e.g. inline definition of the file content?

Tags: docker, shell, dockerfile, sh

When building a project of mine, I first build a docker image and then build the project on it. Currently I have a Docker.file (3 lines) which defines the image to build.

Is it possible to defined the content of a Dockerfile inline with the build command? This way I could get rid of the Dockerfile and probably even work with vars from the shell so I can change my base image dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I build a Dockerfile without having it predefined as an actual file?

You can stream dockerfile content to standard input. `docker build -`.

You can create a temporary directory, in which you create a dockerfile file, and use that directory to `docker build`.

> Is it possible to defined the content of a Dockerfile inline with the build command?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks, so this would be for example `echo -e "FROM alpine:latest\nRUN echo 'Hello, World!'" | docker build -`